# SciPy optimization to a machine learning model

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

Recently I have been facing a problem which I think that SciPy might be a good candidate to solve. However, I have not been able to properly apply it. Not sure if I am missing something or if what I am looking for is actually not possible at all.

This is a fictitious example which I made to makes things more clear and easier to visualize. My case is way more complicated. However, what I want to find out is how many dogs and cats would there be given a specific number of rats?

````
from sklearn.svm import SVR
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

n_dogs = [10, 5, 5, 2, 19, 12, 1,2]
n_cats = [5, 100, 5, 3, 1000, 0, 1,2]
n_rats = [100, 0, 50, 30, 0, 1000, 10, 5]


X = np.array([n_dogs, n_cats]).T
y = np.array([n_rats]).T 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)    
model = RandomForestRegressor()
model.fit(X,y)

#Boundaries of condition
bnds = [(100,500), (100,150)]
#Initial guesses
x0 = [300,125]
#Predict from condition
residual_plant = minimize(lambda x: model.predict([[12,8]]), x0, method='SLSQP',bounds=bnds,options = {'eps': np.radians(5.0)})
print(residual_plant)```
````

Comment: SLSQP and basically all of those methods assume twice-differentiability and `model.predict` surely is not! Basically: you use gradient/hessian-based continuous-optimization methods on a black-box / non-differentiable problem.

Comment: Thank you sascha. Would you suggest me any python tutorial on it please?